# Login con Session en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session

tengo que hacer el modelo de datos del servidor de una aplicación móvil, donde tengo que añadir/mostrar/modificar/eliminar.. datos de la BBDD en MySQL, estoy desarrollando con android studio.
He hecho un `Webservice` con en PHP donde hago peticiones desde el cliente con la libreria `Volley`, hasta ahí todo bien.
El problema viene que esto lo tengo que hacer con su correcta seguridad y necesito crear sesiones para los clientes, de dos tipos: administradores y usuarios, donde si no estás logueado como administrador no puedas hacer según que acciones.
El webservice me funciona, consigo modificar,añadir,buscar.. todo pero necdesito hacerlo con sessions porque si no no es nada seguro, el .php no está correctamente tratado y además no consigo hacer funcionarlo con sessions.
Alguien me podría hechar una mano? Gracias!

Webservice funcionando sin sessions:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$usu_usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$usu_password=$_POST['password'];

$sql = " SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= ? AND password= ? ";

$sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$sentencia->bind_param('ss',$usu_usuario,$usu_password);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}
$sentencia->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: Por qué no utilizas roles de usuario?

Comment: los estoy utilizando, tengo 2 roles.

Comment: Necesitas utilizar la función `session_start()`, investiga un poco sobre ella, modifica tu pregunta con tus dudas y será un placer ayudarte :)